# PRE TAG not working in theme, created pre tag not working with break line

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I am using wordpress theme , but there was not working pre tag , so i have created my pre tag , all is good but when break line not working.

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you add a fiddle or working demo

Comment: We need to see some working code here, reproducing the issue

Comment: Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  pre {
  word-break: break-all; /* webkit */
  word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: pre;
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* fennec */
  white-space: pre-wrap;
    white-space: pre\9; /* IE7+ */
}
```

try using this, might be it works.

Comment: Thanks but it is not doing line break . like i want to write two line in pre tag..  

Line 1 :  This is my test page 
Line 2 : This is my second line 

output in pre tag showing  in one line.

This is my test page  This is my second line

Comment: try using <code></code> tag inside your <pre> tag. Like `<pre><code>this is first line. this is second line</code></pre>`

Comment: i am using this theme https://themeforest.net/item/magazine-vibe-a-powerful-news-magazine-theme/13924332 this theme not having pre tag enable, so i have insert one custome css code .codeStyle as shown in above image. i am using it is like <pre class="codeStyle">  TEXT TEXT </pre> . all thing is working except new line.